# Having problems trying to use a private class declared in header file in the cpp file

Tags: c++

I'm doing a Binary Tree implementation and to do that I have 2 files, a header and an implementation .cpp file. In the header file I have declared in the private area a class 'Node', and in the .cpp file I have a function that returns 'Node*', however when I try to compile my code I receive an error saying "Unknown type 'Node'" in the function declaration.

Relevant code:

```
//in .h
private:
    class Node {
        public:

            Node* left;
            Node* right;
            int data;
            Node(int n) {
                this->data = n;
                this->left = NULL;
                this->right = NULL;
            }


    };

//in .cpp
Node* Binary_Ordered_Tree_int::insert(Node* n, int i) {
  if(n == NULL) {
      return new Node(i);
  }
  if(n->data <= i) {
      n->right = insert(n->right, i);
  }
  else {
      n->left = insert(n->left, i);
  }
  return n;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Because the return type comes before the function name (and its containing class), the compiler doesn't know that it has to look inside the class. So you either tell it to:

```
Binary_Ordered_tree_int::Node* Binary_Ordered_tree_int::insert(Node* n, int i)
```

or, if you have C++11 available, you use trailing return types so that the return type is in the context of the class:

```
auto Binary_Ordered_tree_int::insert(Node* n, int i) -> Node*
```

Comment: Very cool with the trailing return type! Also, couldn't one use `decltype(auto)` if the function was implemented in the header (templates)?

Comment: You could use just `auto` if you have C++14 and you're in a header, but `decltype(auto)` will deduce the wrong thing - specifically, it will deduce different things for the two returns and fail to compile, but if there was only the return of the local variable, it would deduce a reference return type, which would be very wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! It's a quirk I was not expecting.